# JPA Repository not returning all values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to return an array of Double from my repository class. But the repository returns only the first element (i.e. avg(colA)) in the array and modifies the array size to 1.

Repository class:

```
.
.
.
@Query(value="select avg(colA), avg(colB), avg(colC) from Table where ID=?1 group by ID", nativeQuery=true)
public Double[] findData(long id);
.
.
.
```

My service class:

```
.
.
.
@Autowired
TableRepository repo;

long Id = 123;
Double[] arr = new Double[3]; 
arr = repo.findData(Id);

system.Out.println(arr.length); //Returns 1, which is supposed to be 5
system.Out.println(arr[1]); // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
.
.
.
```

What I'm trying: Return an array with elements having average values of the columns. Ideally the elements should have, arr[0] = avg(colA), arr[1] = avg(colB), arr[2] = avg(colC). But the returned array has only arr[0] in it and the sizeof(arr) is just 1 instead of 3. I'm not able to figure out why only the first value is being returned?
The query works fine on the database. Is it related to some array referencing? How to overcome this without writing a separate class to act as the return type?

Comment: May be there is only one record that satisfy the condition.

Comment: Why should `arr` have a length of 5? If I remember correctly, defining the return type as `Double[]` makes Spring Data only return the first selected value and the array contains an element for each row. From the definition you've given Spring Data doesn't know that there is only one matching row (which is only a guess by me too). Try `List<Double[]>` instead - or if that doesn't work then `List<Object[]>` should.

Comment: @Thomas I'm returning the average of a few columns. Its a linear 1D array with each element representing the mean of a column. I'm trying to return average of 3 columns . arr[0] = avg(colA), arr[1] = avg(colB), arr[2] = avg(colC). But the returned array has only arr[0] in it and the sizeof(arr) is also just 1 instead of 3

Comment: Well, see BuildSlayer's answer: your query returns 3 average values so you only get one row. However, Spring Data doesn't actually analyze the query to reason about the number of possible rows but has to assume there could be more than 1. Note that Spring Data needs to map the JDBC result to Java types somehow and what it does here is assume you mean to return one element from multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `List<Double[]>` instead of `Double[]`.

I populated an H2 table:

```
INSERT INTO billionaires (first_name, last_name, career, num1, num2) VALUES
  ('Aliko', 'Dangote', 'Billionaire Industrialist', 500, 222),
  ('Bill', 'Gates', 'Billionaire Tech Entrepreneur', 599, 333),
  ('Folrunsho', 'Alakija', 'Billionaire Oil Magnate', 600, 444);
```

then tested Thomas' theory by creating two methods:

```
@Query(value="select avg(id), avg(num1), avg(num2) from billionaires", nativeQuery=true)
Double[] findData();

@Query(value="select avg(id), avg(num1), avg(num2) from billionaires", nativeQuery=true)
List<Double[]> findData2();
```

And called both:

```
System.out.println("With Double[]:");
Double[] avgs = repo.findData();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(avgs));
System.out.println("With List<Double[]>:");
List<Double[]> avgs2 = repo.findData2();
avgs2.forEach(doubles -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doubles)));
```

Output:

```
With Double[]:
[2.0]
With List<Double[]>:
[2.0, 566.0, 333.0]
```